# How do I highlight unwelded UV vertex?

Tags: uv-image-editor

While working in editing mode, I noticed that the UV image on the object looked garbled so I clicked on the vertex to see where it was on the UV editor. Turns out when I edited the area to remove a 5 sided face it caused a point to appear in 2 different parts, in other words, the UV point wasn't welded and not at a seam. Then I stumbled into another unwelded stray point.

Got me to wondering... 
Is there was a way to highlight all points that are not fully welded in the UV editor?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do what you wanted, but it takes some steps and a addon, TexTools for Blender:

https://blenderartists.org/t/textools-for-blender/700811

http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/

Place the Addon into: C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons, so it can appear in your addon list in blender.

Here's the steps if you wanted to do this way, we're essentially just creating a mesh from the uv map, extruding it, and applying a subdivision surface modifier, where the mesh get's crumppled it's a breaking point in the UV.

So, step 1, gather your mesh and uv map together.

[image]

Step 2, using the addon, in the uv editor apply the function, Create UV Mesh.

[image]

Step 3, show it in solid form, by going in the object properties and setting the display mode.

[image]

Step 4, select the new mesh and extrude it.

[image]

Step 5, apply the subdivision modifier to see where the mesh breaks, that's a UV point break.
[image]

Step 6, using the information give on step 5, check the uv map where the mesh breaked on the subdivision modifier. There are your UV points break highlighted.
[image]

A ugly 6 steps solution, but it works.

The add-on is highly recommended if you like more tools for UVing, just a tip,

Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

If I undestand you correctly, you could change the selection mode to face select button down in the menu and then select all the faces by pressing a. Then you can go back to vertex select and press Ctrl + i to invert the selection

Comment: This will not highlight vertex that are found in more than one location within a UV layout.